# What base font-size should I use for each break-point?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I always have the same question in my head when I start a new project.

What "base font-size" should I use for each break-point in bootstrap?

I usually use the following font-sizes.

```
Lg = base font-size: font-size: 16px

Md = base font-size: font-size: 14px

Sm = base font-size: font-size: 13px

Xs = base font-size: font-size: 12px
```

What base font-size do you usually use in your projects?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Maybe ask this one over at [Graphic Design Stack Exchange with the website-design tag](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design)?

Comment: @ourmandave thank you!. I will ask there :)